# Expectation of a random variable given another random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

> Under a group insurance policy, an insurer agrees to pay all of the
>   medical bills incurred during the year by employees of a small
>   company, up to a maximum total of one million dollars. The total
>   amount of bills incurred, *X*, has probability density function where
>   *f*(*x*)= $\frac{x(4-x)}{9}$ for 0 $\leq$ *x* $\leq$ 3, and 0 otherwise, where *x* is measured in millions. Let *Y* be the total
>   amount of money paid. Compute $\mathop{{}\mathbb{E}}$[*Y*] and
>   var[*Y*].

So for this question, I was thinking of computing the expectation of *X*, and then if it was greater than 1, the expectation for *Y* would be 1,000,000, otherwise it would be $\mathop{{}\mathbb{E}}$[*X*]*1,000,000. Is this the correct strategy? If so, would I go about computing the variance the same way? If not, what is the best way to go about this?

Edit: I actually realized that to get the expectation of *Y*, I need to take the integral of *xf(x)* from 0 to 1, and then add the integral of *f(x)* from 1 to infinity, in order to account for if x is less than 1,000,000 and greater than 1,000,000. I ended up getting around 0.935, but I'm still stumped on how to get the variance of *Y*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not correct. For one thing, if $E[X]>1$ this only implies that sometimes $X>1$ and then sometimes (those times) $Y=1,000,000$ ; but sometimes it will still happen that $X<1$ , and in those cases $Y=X * 1,000,000$, so, the mean will be below: $E[Y]<1,000,000$.

You should first write the formula for $Y$. To avoid messing with the one millon factor, I'l denote by $Z$ the amount of money paid in millions (hence $Y= 1,000,000 Z$).

Then
$$Z=\begin{cases}
 X & \text{if } X \le 1\\
1 &  \text{if } X >1 
\end{cases}
$$

Now  , using $E[g(X)] = \int g(x) f_X(x)dx:$

$$E[Z] = \int_0^1 x \frac{x(4-x)}{9} dx+ \int_1^3  1 \frac{x(4-x)}{9} dx$$

and

$$E[Z^2] = \int_0^1 x^2 \frac{x(4-x)}{9} dx+ \int_1^3  1 \frac{x(4-x)}{9} dx$$

from which we can get the variance of $Z$.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Ah, I actually just made an edit on my post around the same time you posted -- I think we're on the same page, I got those exact integrals and ended up with 0.935. However, I'm still stumped on how to get the variance of _Y_, any ideas?

Comment: You just use $\sigma_Z^2=E[Z^2] - E[Z]^2$. See added equation